# My Javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i am working with javascript on rails. My code wants to submit the form_for when i clicked the save button. Please help me. Thanks!

*edit*

I want to make the button outside the form_for

```
edit.html.erb

  <% @sheets.each do |getsheets| %>
      <%= image_tag "sheets/#{getsheets.sheetimage.split('/')[-2]}/#{getsheets.sheetimage.split('/')[-1]}" %>
      <div>

        <%= form_for getsheets , :url => sheet_attachment_path(getsheets.sheetid,getsheets.sheetid), :html => {id: 'editsheets'} do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :"Name: " %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :sheetid, :value => getsheets.sheetid %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :projectid, :value => getsheets.projectid %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :sheetimage, :value => getsheets.sheetimage %>

        <% end %>

      </div>
      <br>
  <% end %>
  <div>


    <%= button_tag "Save", id: "saveallsheets", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>

  </div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#saveallsheets').on('click', function() {     $('#editsheets').submit(); });
});
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Try to add `return false;` as last line of your js function.

Comment: Nothing happens on my console when i click the save button.

Comment: Multiple forms with same id `editsheets` ?

Comment: Yes it is multiple forms for editing a sheet. I want to change the name of each sheet at save at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<%= f.submit "Save", :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" name="commit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

or this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#editsheets').submit();">Save</button>
```

or in your js

```
$(function() {
  $('#saveallsheets').on('click', function() { 
    $('#editsheets').trigger("submit.rails"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to make the button outside form_for